# Why is the "Word of the Day" screensaver giving me false information?

Tags: macos, screensaver

I'm using the "Word of the Day" screensaver under OSX 10.8.

It says "Press the D key to see more.", however hitting the D, or any other key, instead brings up the password screen used to terminate the screensaver and get back to work.

Is there something I might have messed up, or it's just a sentence they forgot there but isn't really supposed to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1221593?start=0&tstart=0) it is supposed to open the "Dictionary" app. However, according to that discussion doesn't seem to work if the screensaver is set to require a password.

I have not tried on MacOS X 10.8, but on 10.9 it is no longer possible to disable the password of the screensaver and only set the time after which the screensaver activates. So it seems that it is no longer supposed to work and it is a sentence they forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this –
• Open the **Dictionary.app**, select `Dictionary > Preferences…` from the menu bar.
• Check if '*New Oxford American Dictionary (American English)*' is checked in the list of sources. If it is not, check the box and wait for the contents to download.
• Then quit Dictionary.app and try the "Word of the Day" screen saver again.